# ffmpeg hls with aes encryption

Tags: android, ffmpeg, aes, http-live-streaming, android-videoview

I was trying to create an encrypted hls stream using ffmpeg. I've seen other questions related to this. 
I've created a video.key file with the following content:

```
12345678901234567890123456789011
```

I've also created a key_info file with the following contents:

```
http://10.10.102.223:59164/trial/video.key
video.key
```

I have a mp4 file : jellies.mp4
and I was trying to transcode and encrypt it using

```
ffmpeg -i jellies.mp4 -hls_time 5 -hls_key_info_file key_info playlist.m3u8
```

After I was done transcoding I put the folder on a server and tried to access it on a client android app.

The app contains a VideoView to which the url is fed. And I believe that decryption is done automatically.

But the app is not working . It shows the following errors:

```
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -1007)
```

After this I tried the transcoding again ,this time without encryption ,using:

```
ffmpeg -i jellies.mp4 -hls_time 5 playlist.m3u8
```

This played perfectly on the app.

Using packet capture I'm able to see the various packets sent and received .

And the key is being received perfectly.

Then why is the stream not working.

Is it because I didn't encrypt it properly ? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If u have error -1007 (`MEDIA_ERROR_MALFORMED`) check encoding on your keyfile and number of symbols.

For example in UTF-8 keyfile with lesser or greater number of symbols than 16 (128bit), this error occurs on some players.